# Spacebar usage according to WCAG 2.0

Tags: html, keyboard, accessibility, wcag2.0

I want to know, according to WCAG 2.0, in which cases the spacebar is used to interact within the page.

Is it use in the same cases as the enter key?

Should I provide the same function to the enter key and the spacebar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as WCAG 2.0 it says specifically to use space bar only in 3 cases:

https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-wai-aria-practices-20090224/

1. Checks the radio button with keyboard focus (this is a special case when using tab and no radio buttons have been marked as checked (https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-wai-aria-practices-20090224#kbd_general_ex).
2. It is recommended that the space bar be used for selection for Drag drop support (https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-wai-aria-practices-20090224#dragdrop)
3. Checkbox - Space bar toggles checkboxes, if the list items are checkable (https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-wai-aria-practices-20090224#listbox)

The WCAG only mentions a guideline:

"The TAB key moves keyboard focus to the widget, and other keys operate the features of the widget, typically cursor keys, Enter key and Spacebar. The actual keys are up to the developer, but best practices recommend using the same key bindings that are used to control similar widgets in common GUI operating systems like Microsoft Windows®, Apple OSX® and UNIX Desktops like GNOME and GTK."

Frankly its left to the user's interpretation, and based on what you are trying to implement, you would probably have to see the existing behaviour of similar components on popular tools/web sites/ browser behaviour and make a logical decision.

Comment: The links go to *WAI-ARIA Best Practices* ([a draft from 2009](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-wai-aria-practices-20090224/); instead of the draft from 2013, *WAI-ARIA 1.0 Authoring Practices*), but this is not WCAG 2.0.

Comment: That is true. But WAI-ARIA best practices are derived from WCAG-2.0, and mine is but one answer, I could update the link to the draft in 2013

Answer (score 4):

Do not change the native behavior of controls. That can mess with users.

A hyperlink can be fired by pressing the enter key. But a true button can be fired by pressing the enter key or the space bar. When a hyperlink has focus and the user presses the space bar, the page will scroll one screenful. If there isn’t more to scroll then the user just experiences nothing.

I think it’s also worth mentioning that events triggered by a space bar only fire when the key is released, whereas using the Enter key will fire the event as soon as you press the key down (prior to releasing it).

I have a CodePen from another example that shows this: http://s.codepen.io/aardrian/debug/PZQJyd

If you are making something like a `<div>` clickable and trying to add keyboard interaction, then do not use a `<div>`. Use the right element for the purpose, which I briefly outline as:

- Does the control take me to another page? Use an anchor (`<a href>`).
- Does the control change something on the current page? Use `<button>`.
- Does the control submit form fields? Use `<input type=submit>` or `<button type=submit>`.